# `Intl`, `padStart` can't be used in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to port my React web app to React Native.

Part of my codes contains the following:

```
String(now.getMonth()+1)).padStart(2,0)
```

This is to create a month string that is padded. This segment works fine in my React web app but in React Native, it prompts: `underfined is not a function`. If I just output `now.getMonth()+1`, the code works fine.

I also tried to:

```
let formatter=new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
});
```

So that I can format a number like `1,234` but the error message says: `Can't find variable Intl`. The code works in my React web app.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: I just add `react-intl` dependency to the project and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on React Native about that: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18375

I "fixed" adding `lodash` as a dependency, to your code will be like that:

```
import { padStart } from "lodash";
padStart(String(now.getMonth()+1)),2,0)
```

Hope it helps you.